# Image based texture mapping

Tags: image, image-processing

I am researching texture mapping and would like to implement a software for this purpose. What exactly I want is this approach :

[image]

I need your suggestions for:

1. Is opengl suitable for development?
2. Do you know any documentation that describes this subject?
3. What is the domain name of this subject? **Texture mapping**? When i search the web i get 3d samples only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Color Blending.

Useful links:

[Here](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/blend-textures-with-photos/) and [here](http://www.cgtextures.com/content.php?action=tutorial&name=blendif) for photoshop examples for better visual understanding.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976070.aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes) for a more academic information.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/11/03/detail-textures.aspx) and [here](http://www.gamasutra.com/features/20020626/hargreaves_01.htm) your can find a technique for adding fine grain texture to a flat color texture.